# TI iBeacon configuration

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, iot, ibeacon, texas-instruments

Hello I've got some iBeacons, but I don't know anything about manufacturer, I need anyway to configure that beacons with custom UUID, Major and  Minor parameters.

So after search around I've understand that the chip inside is an CC2541 - HMSensor. As I understand well it's produced by Texas Instruments, but unfortunately any app I've tried (Even SensorTag both on iOS and Android) to edit iBeacon tags failed, no one seems to be able to allow me change UUID, Major and Minor.

I hope that someone could help me to understand better in which situation I am. Phisically the beacon is just the CC2541 board (https://www.instructables.com/id/Turn-your-CC2541-based-HM-10-Bluetooth-Smart-Modul/) with a module to attach a button battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't know what firmware is installed on the CC2541.

**It is quite likely that the firmware installed does not allow you to remotely configure the beacon identifiers using an app.  This would be the case with base firmware.**

If your device does have base firmware, you'd need a  CP2102 USB to Serial Converter as described in the link you have in the question, then you'd need to wire it up to your CC2541 and then you'd need a serial cable to connect it to your computer.  From that point you may be able to use a terminal program to set the identifiers if the CC2541 has base firmware.

If your CC2541 does not have base firmware, you'll need an additional  jig that allows you to flash new firmware so you can get the identifiers configured.

If you are just using these devices because they are convenient, it would be far easier to order new off-the-shelf beacons that are configurable.  If you actually do want to learn to use this hardware, I'd suggest getting a development setup going through tutorials like you have linked above.

Comment: Thank you, you have confirmed unfortunately the worst scenario, maybe the best idea is to order new beacons